# What are the benefits of running a database on Amazon EBS instead of in the EC2 instance?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm going to need to host a website with an underlying database. I know I can either run the database on the instance itself, or I can have it on an EBS volume. I'm going to be backing up to S3 every so often, and I was wondering what the benefits were of running the database on EBS and not the instance itself.

Comment: looks like i'll just end up putting the db on ebs then and running with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EBS volume will be fast, super fast.  It's basically attached to your instance as a drive.  However a drawback to this is that you'll only be able to attach it to one instance at a time.  I've heard of EBS volumes dropping...this article talks about some of that stuff...i would just let it live on the instance it self, and snapshot it from there if it's going to be a small db.

http://agilesysadmin.net/ec2-outage-lessons

Answer (score 1):

Instance storage will disappear if your instance crash. EBS is more reliable. Arguably you don't even need additional S3 copy (bit you need normal backup as with any database).

Answer (score 0):

Instance store will disappear if your instance is crashed, + EBS volume got quite a good problem recently - though this is good over instance-store, I would suggest you to have a look at **[Amazon Relational Database Service](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) (Amazon RDS)**. I had used it for one my project and it's super cool.

Amazon RDS has got quite good advantages, featuring:

- Automated Backups
- DB Snapshots
- Automatic Host Replacement
- Replication

When you compare EBS with RDS, both are charged where as little extra on RDS when compared to EBS, but its worth it. Amazon takes care of everything and if your site is traffic-driven, it has got solution to replicate automatically.

Comment: RDS is actually just EC2 + EBS with several automation in place.